# Media query workaround in IE8

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I was looking to add CSS media query workaround for ie8 in my code..

I came across css3-mediaqueries.js

http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/

But could not find details or example of how to implement it in my site.

Could you please provide any example for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the site it says "Usage: just include the script in your pages." and has a few more rules on how its used.  It appears to only work for media queries that are inside the style sheet and not media query attributes and won't work with @imported CSS files.

**UPDATE**

Based on our conversation, the goal is to serve up one stylesheet for the desktop and another for tablets.  The natural solution is to do the following:

```
<link media="screen and (max-width: x)" href="tablet.css">
<link media="screen and (min-width: x)" href="desktop.css">
```

The problem is that IE6, 7, and 8 will apply both stylesheets.  Fortunately, we know for a fact that IE6, 7, and 8 will never be on tablets (or at least not tablets in the modern sense), so we can use [Internet Explorer Conditional Comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to prevent these versions of IE from seeing the tablet CSS.  Here is an example using downlevel-revealed conditional comments:

```
<![if gte IE 9]>
    <!-- This code is visible to IE9 and above and all non-IE browsers. -->
    <link media="screen and (max-width: x)" href="tablet.css">
<![endif]>
<link media="screen and (min-width: x)" href="desktop.css">
```

For any non-IE browser, `<![if gte IE 9]>` is a nonsense tag which is ignored.  For IE browsers, they do a logical check: `if(version >= 9) use content`.  IE 6, 7, and 8 will therefor ignore the tablet css and only see `<link href="desktop.css">`.  You could alternatively use the more verbose:

```
<![if gte IE 9]>
    <!-- This code is visible to IE9 and above and all non-IE browsers. -->
    <link media="screen and (max-width: x)" href="tablet.css">
    <link media="screen and (min-width: x)" href="desktop.css">
<![endif]>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <!-- This code is only visible to IE8 and below. -->
    <link href="desktop.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Hmm..so does it mean if i want to use <link media...desktop.css> that won't work ? Also any other simpler option apart from Respond.js?

Comment: Right, you will need to do the media query in the CSS itself: `@media all {...}`

Comment: So within the CSS, does it support media query completely...like if i write @media min-width:....Actually i am wanting to avoid doing that for easy maintenance between the 2 separate CSS..

Comment: That is what it appears to do.  Can you give more examples on what you're trying to do?  If you're just doing a min-width test, are you trying to have a mobile and a normal version of your site?  If so, you could just assume that old IE always gets the normal version and use IE conditional comments to make it work.

Comment: I M looking to apply 2 different CSS files for different screen size (using min-width, max-width and not exactly device-width as of now)...i think conditional comments would have been fine, but i do not think we can specifiy width attributes there..

Comment: What I'm saying is that since we know that IE < 9 will never be a tablet, we can simply force those browsers never to consider the tablet style: `<![if gte IE 9]><link media="..." href="tablet.css"><![endif]>`

Comment: I did not quite get that..could u pls merge the 2 for desktop and ipad so that i can get the complete picture...As of now, i plan to show tablet vErsion on desktop IE also at lower browser sizes..

Comment: Hey thx a lot..i now understand clearly what u r trying to say...But my only question is i wanted to apply tablet css on IE8 @ lower screen sizes (or say @ tablet sizes) which i think cannot happen in the approach u just mentioned...so can we fix that?

Comment: Then you need something like respond.js

Comment: Actually i did try Respond.js before asking here...but did not find that easy to implement for applying locally and has CDN settings...i m looking at something simple to implement..

Answer (score 0):

Skeleton is a great library for creating sites using media queries, the [skeleton site](http://getskeleton.com/) itself is one giant example.

Comment: Thx a lot..But Skeleton seems to be a full-fledged framework..i am looking at just css media query support in older browsers..i m implementing responsive design on my own...

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include the script anywhere in your page, the library will do the rest. Quote from the project homepage:

> Usage: just include the script in your pages.

Always helps to read the whole page!

Comment: Actually i want to use media queries with 2 <link media...for desktop.css and ipad.css

Comment: Ah yes, the library doesn't support that